# How to set the value of an specific array attribute of an Angular model interface?

Tags: angular, rest

Let's say I have the following two jsons from a REST API.

http://myapi/users/

```
[
    {
        "userId": "1",
        "userName": "John",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": "3"
            },
            {
                "roleId": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userId": "2",
        "userName": "Mary",
        "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": "5"
            },
            {
                "roleId": "6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

http://myapi/user/1/roles

```
[
    {
        "roleId": "3",
        "roleName": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "roleId": "4",
        "roleName": "Operator"
    }
]
```

In Angular I have the following:

```
export interface User {

    userId: string;
    userName: string;
    roles: Role[];
}

export interface Role {

    roleId: string;
    roleName: string;
}
```

Now I want to create an observable that gets data from the first endpoint and then populates the roles attribute of each user getting data from the second enpoint.

The first part is ok. Need to know how to do the second part which is to populate the roles attribute specifically.

Need to do that so that I can have the roles attribute with the remaining fields from role (such as roleName), not just the roleId.

```
export class UserService {

  users$: Observable<User[]> | null = null;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUsersData() {   

    this.users$ = this.getUsers();

    //how to write here the foreach to populate the roles attribute from this.users$ calling getUserRoles?

  }

  getUsers(){

    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://myapi/users/')
    .pipe(
      first()
    );
  }

  getUserRoles(userId: string | null){

    return this.httpClient.get<Role[]>('http://myapi/user/' + userId + 'roles')
    .pipe(
      first()
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate the roles attribute of each user with the corresponding role data, you can use the forkJoin operator from RxJS. Here's an updated version of your code that achieves this:

```
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class UserService {

  users$: Observable<User[]> | null = null;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUsersData() {
    this.users$ = this.getUsers().pipe(
      switchMap(users => {
        const userRolesRequests = users.map(user => this.getUserRoles(user.userId));
        return forkJoin(userRolesRequests).pipe(
          map(rolesData => {
            return users.map((user, index) => {
              user.roles = rolesData[index];
              return user;
            });
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://myapi/users/').pipe(
      first()
    );
  }

  getUserRoles(userId: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Role[]>('http://myapi/user/' + userId + '/roles').pipe(
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

In the getUsersData() method, after fetching the users, we use the switchMap operator to switch to a new observable that combines all the requests for fetching user roles using forkJoin. This creates an array of observables, one for each user's roles request.

The forkJoin operator waits for all the observables to complete and returns an array of the combined results. We then use the map operator to iterate over the users and roles data arrays, assigning the roles to the corresponding user.

Finally, the updated users$ observable will emit the users with their populated roles.

Have a happy codding!

Comment: Just one thing. What if I have more attributes that need the same thing. Let's say Users also has a Address[ ] and Phones [ ] attributes that also require a call to getUserAddresses and getUserPhones respectively.

Comment: Your two most recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.